# Handle Apple Pencil Touch Event with UITouchTypeStylus

Tags: ios, touch, stylus, stylus-pen

I need to handle specific action for UITouchTypeStylus touch event and have specific action for button in view.

If i click button with apple pencil both event is triggered.

let me know,how to trigger only UITouchTypeStylus touch event when click button with apple pencil ?
or
how to handle if we touch buttons or any of actions.. when even it’s stylus.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be a UIButton subclass with overwritten touchesBegan/Moved/Ended methods and blocks or delegate methods to call passing the touch type. Then check the touch type and invoke the appropriate functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet*) touches withEvent: (UIEvent*) event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch type] == UITouchTypeStylus)
    {
        //your code...
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some context around your source-code.
Code-only answers are difficult to understand.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.